# Duplicate function implementation in angularjs

Tags: angular, duplicates

**The code is showing a problem of duplicate function when compiling**

```js
export class LeaderService {

  constructor() { }

  getLeaders(): Promise<Leader[]> {
    return new Promise(resolve=> {
      // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
      setTimeout(() => resolve(LEADERS), 1000);
    });  
  }

  getLeaders(id: string): Promise<Leader> {
    return new Promise(resolve=> { 
      // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
      setTimeout(() => resolve(LEADERS.filter((leader) => (leader.id === id))[0]), 1000);
    });    
  }

  getFeaturedLeader(): Promise<Leader> {
    return new Promise(resolve=> { 
      // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
      setTimeout(() => resolve(LEADERS.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]), 1000);
    });    
  }
```

**problem showing is**

*ERROR in src/app/services/leader.service.ts(12,3): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
src/app/services/leader.service.ts(19,3): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.*

Comment: Please post your code instead of images.

Comment: Should this be tagged/titled with Angular vs. angularjs? Code looks like typescript.